# ASN1 bad tag when completing ssl certificate request in IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, ssl-certificate

Consider a scenario of importing a `.cer` file for use in IIS 7.

The CSR was NOT created on this machine. After receiving a `.cer` file from the CA, the Complete Certificate Request wizard prompts for the CA's response and your friendly name for use in IIS.

> CertEnroll: CX509Enrollment::p_InstallResponse: ASN1 bad tag value met.

How can you avoid this error and complete the certificate request in IIS7?
Is this due to the CSR not being created on this machine? [Digicert seems to think it's not the issue](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7.htm).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check this article [ASN1 bad tag value met.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/webtopics/asn1-bad-tag-value-met-error-when-processing-a-certificate-request-in-iis-7)